# Python from binary to dict

Tags: python, json, dictionary, utf-8

In my project i have a binary like this:

```
data1 = b'"[5, \\"WEB99\\", \\"Test\\", true, \\"2018-08-12\\"]"'
```

i would extract some informations (without \), for example date1[0] -> 5 or data1[4] -> "2018-08-12"

For doing this i try to convert my binary in a dict using json like this:

```
data1 = data1.decode('utf-8')
```

then

```
d1 = json.dumps(data1, default='utf-8')
```

but the result is a mess:

> '"\"[5, \\\"WEB99\\\", \\\"Test\\\", true, \\\"2018-08-12\\\"]\""'

how can i convert in a pythonic way my binary data in a format for extracting values?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are loading the data to Python, not dumping it from Python, so you should use `d1 = json.loads(data1, encoding="utf8-")`

Comment: thanks so mutch, i try with loads but if i transform the result using list() i receive a list containing every single char ['[', '5', ',', ' ', '"', 'W', 'E', 'B', '9', '9', '"', ',', ' ', '"', 'T', 'e', 's', 't', '"', ',', ' ', 't', 'r', 'u', 'e', ',', ' ', '"', '2', '0', '1', '8', '-', '0', '8', '-', '1', '2', '"', ']']

Comment: That's because you've probably double-serialized a JSON list. You shouldn't have to call `list` on the result of `json.load`. Somewhere, you had a serialized JSON list, something like `'["foo", "bar", "baz"]'`, and then you *reserialized* that string, giving you a JSON string, which *happens* to be a serialized JSON list.

Comment: `json.loads(str(json.loads(data1)))` should work

Comment: @mad_ yes, it should, but the OP should definitely be aware of the source of this error, and fix it at the source.

Comment: @mad_TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I thought your explanation was enough. Just showed the application. mauel: you might need to convert it into string

Comment: @ManuelSanti yes dude, because you have to decode the bytes first. How are you ending up with this data in the first place.

Comment: @mad_ yeah, that was mostly meant for the OP :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this first:

```
data1 = data1.decode('utf-8')
```

then

```
a = json.loads(json.loads(data1,encoding='utf-8'))
```

> [5, 'WEB99', 'Test', True, '2018-08-12']

at this point you have a list and could extract values as you want:

```
a[3]
```

True

Answer (score 1):

You should use `loads` instead of `dumps`. However, in your case, I used `loads` 2 times.

```
data1 = b'"[5, \\"WEB99\\", \\"Test\\", true, \\"2018-08-12\\"]"'
your_list = json.loads(json.loads(data1.decode('utf-8')))
```

Comment: i try but the response is : TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'

Comment: @ManuelSanti sure, I didn't add a `decode` to the example